# Can't make longtable and fancyhdr get on well

Tags: fancyhdr, xltabular

I've to write a document with a table made of a great amount of entries and two columns (the second of which should take as much space in width as possible). I've read online that the `xltabular` could help me in that way.

The problem is that in the first page of the document I need a very high header, so I've defined a `fancypagestyle` for the first page redefining `\headheight` to `0.4 \textwidth`. In this way, however, the table does not calculate the lengths again and finishes out of the bottom edge of the page.

This is the code I've tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\fancypagestyle{headerPage}{
 \renewcommand{\headheight}{0.4 \textwidth}
}

\begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{headerPage}
 \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{r | X}
   A & \lipsum[2] \\
   B & \lipsum[2] \\
   C & \lipsum[2] \\
   D & \lipsum[2-4] \\
   E & \lipsum[2] \\
   F & \lipsum[2] \\
 \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the result without setting `\thispagestyle`:

[image: without header]

While this is the one obtained adding the header:
[image: with header]

I think the problem is that the header's height is changed after the table's height is computed, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide,

Lorenzo

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you really have to change the  header height, or to customise the `\maketitle` command?

Comment: Hi @Bernard thanks ;). 
I'd like to create an header on the first page to write my name, some contact information and an image (it is some sort of curriculum), I don't know which is the best approach. Thanks

Comment: Do you need the header on the first page only? Probably a sketch if the desired output would help.

Comment: I was tring to make an header similar to the one in [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cd/a3/53/cda3531b5388bb95f38c7996aa668603.jpg) image. @Bernard 's advice to edit the `\maketitle` command, though, helped me creating the basic structure and bypass the conflict between `xltabular` and `fancyhdr`. Thanks to all of you.